# how can I set DateTimeReceived on an EmailMessage?

Tags: ewsjavaapi

I need to (directly or indirectly) set the `DateTimeReceived` on an `EmailMessage`, so I can call `emailMessage.save()`

I dug into the source (`EmailMessage`, `Item`, `PropertyBag`, `ItemSchema`) but I didn't see a way to set the `Received` header (couldn't find any way to directly access headers) nor a way to set `ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived` (it's marked read-only). Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got advice in an email thread. In case it helps anyone else, you can set properties like `DateTimeReceived` as a `new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0E06, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime)`.

(However, being new to this API, I haven't yet figured out where the reference is for all the possible "extended property definition" values that EWS understands.)